# PHP PDO sqlsrv on IIS - could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pdo

I'm using a Windows 2008 Server with IIS. I've been able to sucessfully install PHP 5.6 and downloaded the drivers for MS SQL Server from Microsoft. I've verified PHP is working. I've verified I'm running non-thread safe and added the following driver references to my php.ini file:

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

When I try to connect to the DB, I simply get a "could not find driver" error. Nothing I've tried has worked. Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "(local)\sqlexpress";

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
try
{
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=PFSMDS2", "", "");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM brands";

$getBrands = $conn->prepare($tsql);
$brands = $getBrands->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach( $brands as $row )
{
echo $row['name'];
}
?>
```

I've scoured StackOverflow and just about every forum imaginable and cannot get this working. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: did you restart IIS?

Comment: Yes, many times thanks.

Comment: did you "1. Put the driver file in your PHP extension directory"? "http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx"

Comment: Yes thanks. Driver files are in the php/ext directory.

Comment: Hi David, did you get this working? Same issue here and exhausted all the usual support avenues..